When to water vegetables
I have been told that it is best to water vegetables in the morning and in the evening/night. Why is this? Why would watering the vegetables in the afternoon damage the plants?
What if it rains?
Thanks.

Every person has own opinions on watering, so the real answer is between it depends and it doesn't matter so much.
So, try to decide what it is best (more convenient) for you, and then think about possible negative effects. Ev. you need to adjust.

on hot part of day and mainly in summer much more water will evaporate, so it is waste water. If you have own infinite sources (or the rain you mention) it doesn't matter. If there are water restrictions, better to use time where watering is more efficient. Depending on climate the evaporation may be significant.

diseases like drops of water (fungi, but also snails), so various people discourage to water on evening if water cannot dry quick. But it depends on your climate and overall humidity

water pressure: on night, when less people uses water, there may be more pressure, so the irrigations may work better, or quicker.


Myths:

lens effect of drops: no.. focal length make them impossible

plants need more water during night: it may be true but irrelevant. During night there is much more transpiration (spices and Mediterranean plants), but in any cases roots should never be so dry for such hourly changes.


Note: it has also to do with irrigation: most people prefer a lot of water but seldom, so to soak soil also in deep and so less transpiration, but not all plants like that, and some vegetables may not have deep roots, e.g. seedling so you may need to adapt strategies during season. Also there may be dangers of washing away fertilizers and also soil.
So, try to think what it is optimal to you and check. And regularly get feedback from your vegetables: every year is different, every months has own problems.
Also all discussion about not watering leaves. On green houses tomatoes may be cooled down with water on hot days): so we should not be too much against it, but also we should not keep leaves wet for too long (also depending climate and vegetable).
Or maybe your question is wrong. You may be much more precise (which vegetables, where? how do you water things) not to overgeneralize. Thumb rules in my region may be wrong on other places.
